# Invalid Geometry Type Error when using Build Balanced Zones in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geometry

I am trying to use the build balanced zones tool in ArcGIS Pro. The tool description itself says it supports polygons and points. I can't get my points to load in as input features; it's saying invalid geometry type. I have tried loading them in as both a shapefile and as a feature class and its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer fairly quickly. Looks like the tool only works with "point" geometry types. I had dissolved the data previously before trying to run the tool, resulting in "multipoint" geometry. I ran multipart to single part and that fixed the issue.